# Get data from Data reader terminal to a GUI in real time

Tags: c++, linux, qt, user-interface

I am having a data reader which takes the data from a buffer and displays the output to console. Now I want to see the data into a textedit in real time. 
I have seen some examples showing how the data can be read from a text file (non real-time).

Please find the attachment.

```
/* Create a DataReader for the chatMessageTopic Topic (using the appropriate QoS). */
parentReader = chatSubscriber->create_datareader(
    chatMessageTopic.in(),
    DATAREADER_QOS_USE_TOPIC_QOS,
    NULL,
    STATUS_MASK_NONE);
checkHandle(parentReader.in(), "DDS::Subscriber::create_datareader");

/* Narrow the abstract parent into its typed representative. */
chatAdmin = Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::_narrow(parentReader.in());
checkHandle(chatAdmin.in(), "Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::_narrow");

/* Print a message that the MessageBoard has opened. */
cout << "MessageBoard has opened: send ChatMessages...." << endl << endl;

while (!terminated) {
    /* Note: using read does not remove the samples from
       unregistered instances from the DataReader. This means
       that the DataRase would use more and more resources.
       That's why we use take here instead. */

    status = chatAdmin->take(
        msgSeq,
        infoSeq,
        LENGTH_UNLIMITED,
        ANY_SAMPLE_STATE,
        ANY_VIEW_STATE,
        ALIVE_INSTANCE_STATE );
    checkStatus(status, "Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::take");

    for (DDS::ULong i = 0; i < msgSeq->length(); i++) {
       ChatMessage *msg = &(msgSeq[i]);
       cout << msg->index << ": " << msg->content << endl;
       fflush(stdout);
    }

    status = chatAdmin->return_loan(msgSeq, infoSeq);
    checkStatus(status, "Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::return_loan");
```

Comment: QtCreator is an IDE. You're using Qt!

Comment: It'd help to mention that you're using the RTI Connext C++ API.

Comment: Okay Its is Prismtech C++ Program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely don't want that your UI is refreshing at a 1000Hz. So there's no point in running this code in a busy loop. Instead, run it at a reasonable refresh rate, e.g. 30Hz, from a timer.

For performance reasons, it may help to emit row batches as well as individual rows for the log:

Let's abstract this out:

```
class DDSProcessor : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
  DDS::Subscriber * m_chatSubscriber;
  Chat::ChatMessageDataReader * m_chatDataReader = nullptr;
  ...
  Q_SIGNAL void message(const QString &);
  Q_SIGNAL void messages(const QStringList &);
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
    if (ev->timerId() != m_timer.timerId()) return;
    auto status = chatAdmin->take(
        msgSeq,
        infoSeq,
        LENGTH_UNLIMITED,
        ANY_SAMPLE_STATE,
        ANY_VIEW_STATE,
        ALIVE_INSTANCE_STATE );
    checkStatus(status, "Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::take");
    QStringList texts;
    for (DDS::ULong i = 0; i < msgSeq->length(); i++) {
       auto msg = &(msgSeq[i]);
       auto text = tr("%1: %2").arg(msg->index).arg(msg->content);
       texts << text;
       emit message(text);
    }
    emit messages(texts);
    status = chatAdmin->return_loan(msgSeq, infoSeq);
    checkStatus(status, "Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::return_loan");
  }
public:
  void start() {
    auto reader = m_chatSubscriber->create_datareader(
      m_chatMessageTopic.in(), ...);
    checkHandle(read.in(), "DDS::Subscriber::create_datareader");
    m_chatDataReader = Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::_narrow(reader.in());
    checkHandler(m_chatDataReader.in(), "Chat::ChatMessageDataReader::_narrow");
    auto text = tr("MessageBoard had opened: send ChatMessages.");
    emit message(text);
    emit messages(text);
    m_timer.start(this, 1000/30);
  }
  ...
};
```

I'm not familiar with the DDS library enough, but there are some callbacks you should be using to be notified instead, and then you'd emit the signal(s) from the callbacks. That would remove the need for an explicit UI update loop.

All you have to do in the UI, then, is to act on the messages sent out by the DDSProcessor:

```
void setup(DDSProcessor * src, QTextEdit * dst) {
  connect(src, &DDSProcessor::message, dst, &QTextEdit::append);
}
```

Note that both `QTextEdit` and `QPlainTextEdit` are very slow and unsuitable for fast logging. The easiest workaround is to use a list model with a `QListView`, and leverage the batched log entry signal:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QStringListModel logModel;
  QListView view;
  DDSProcessor processor;
  QObject::connect(&processor, &DDSProcessor::messages, &logModel, [&](const QStringList & texts){
    auto row = logModel.rowCount();
    logModel.insertRows(row, texts.count());
    for (auto const & text : texts)
      logModel.setData(model.index(row++), text);
  });
  view.setModel(&logModel);
  view.show();
  view.setUniformItemSizes(true); // needed for performance
  ...
  return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example of logging to GUI synchronously:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QPlainTextEdit edit;
  edit.show();
  int x = 0;
  while (edit.isVisible()) {
    x++;
    edit.appendPlainText(QString("test %1").arg(x));
    qApp->processEvents();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is horrible. It pegs CPU at 100%. Don't do that.

Comment: It won't load CPU at 100% once you put some blocking IO operations in the loop. The data has to come from somewhere. This implementation may be in fact less CPU-expensive than signal-based implementation because it doesn't use timers and doesn't need signal-slot system to work. If data is coming in very small chunks, though, some kind of buffering could help.

Comment: The only blocking IO operation in a loop in the GUI thread should be the event-wait inside of `app.exec()`. Anything else will make the responsiveness suffer. The data is coming, in this case, from a separate worker thread in the library the asker is using, and that library offers callbacks, too, so even polling I suggested isn't the best thing to do - busy-spinning is even worse.